# how to enable authentication of storm ui for security?

Tags: apache-storm

Recently i install the distributed realtime computation system "Storm".
When enable storm ui, everyone can access the storm ui throuth http://xxxxx:8080, and can kill my topology. 
How to enable authentication?

Comment: Which version of Storm you are using?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at [Apache Storm Security](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/SECURITY.md) in general, and particularly the section [UI/LogViewer.](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/SECURITY.md#uilogviewer)

Also, have a loot at [Storm defaults.yaml](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml) configuration file. It contains entries that are related to securing an Apache Storm topology.

And please check which release of Apache Storm that you are using.